# Am I right that 'brew python install --universal' is gone?

Tags: python-2.7, homebrew, macos-sierra, 32-bit

I'm in need of running some old wx stuff with python in 32-bit mode (`arch -i386 python wx.py`) under brewed python, macOS 10.12 will just give

```
arch -i386 python
arch: posix_spawnp: python: Bad CPU type in executable
```

What's the easiest way forward?

the macOS pre-installed one still works and I got the brew libraries working by symlinks *(there is probably a better approach)*

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/wxpython/... /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/wx

arch -i386 /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
```

but I'd prefer an approach where I can rely on brew and pip

I hope I'm just missing out on something obvious on how to get --universal support back using brew.

Answer (score 3):

`--universal` has been deprecated in Homebrew [1.1.8](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/releases/tag/1.1.8) and slowly removed from existing formulae since. The [reason behind](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/pull/2477/files#diff-bd0ba063e0f8aeb1f4a3997d34914c0cR1053) is that "macOS has been 64-bit only since 10.6". You thus can’t rely on Homebrew for this.

Comment: Thx for input! Any suggestions on how to run legacy projects that depends on 32-bit wxpython ?

Comment: You might want to look at [Tigerbrew](https://github.com/mistydemeo/tigerbrew#tigerbrew), a fork of Homebrew that support older OSX's. It does have a [`wxpython`](https://github.com/mistydemeo/tigerbrew/blob/1cdf87c6f13ae0738e5ba0ca31248d2e7efa0bd5/Library/Formula/wxpython.rb) formula that support `--universal`. (I’ve never used it myself)

Comment: universal would have been very useful for Apple Silicon + Intel though, so horrible decision, unless they came up with something else